# For grouping with mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT mf.fm_id,ema.asc_code as 'Xaxis', count(*) as 'Total' 
from els_jobsheet_data as jd 
join master_asc as ma on (jd.asc_id=ma.asc_id ) 
join els_master_asc_l3l4 as ema on jd.els_asc_code =ema.asc_code 
join master_city as mc on mc.city_id=ma.city_id 
join master_state as ms on ms.state_id=mc.state_id 
join master_region as mr on mr.region_id=ms.region_id 
join master_fso as mf on mf.fm_id=mr.fso_id 
where jd.insert_time is not null AND jd.insert_time>='2015-12-01' 
AND jd.insert_time<='2015-12-31'  
group by Xaxis 
order by Xaxis ASC
```

*A query returned-*

```
fm_id    Xaxis    Total
  2       DOA       43
  3       DSRO      12
  1       TRC       12
  9       3423        10
  5       5455        11
  2       2443        13
  7       55AS         2
```

But I want to group it like

```
fm_id    Xaxis    Total
  2       DOA       43
  3       DSRO      12
  1       TRC       12
  9       Other     342
```

(whatever be its total)

i m newbie.Pls help..

Comment: You may find this easier to achieve in the front end, especially if the number of returned records varies.

Comment: What is the rule that puts some of the results into the "Other" group?

Comment: I dont't get it, the query already returned the result you wanted rite?

Answer (score 0):

Use a case expression instead of the raw data.

```
SELECT
      max(mf.fm_id) as fm_id
    , CASE
            WHEN ema.asc_code IN ('DOA', 'DSRO', 'TRC') THEN ema.asc_code
            ELSE 'Other'
      END AS Xaxis
    , COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM els_jobsheet_data AS jd
      JOIN master_asc AS ma ON (jd.asc_id = ma.asc_id)
      JOIN els_master_asc_l3l4 AS ema ON jd.els_asc_code = ema.asc_code
      JOIN master_city AS mc ON mc.city_id = ma.city_id
      JOIN master_state AS ms ON ms.state_id = mc.state_id
      JOIN master_region AS mr ON mr.region_id = ms.region_id
      JOIN master_fso AS mf ON mf.fm_id = mr.fso_id
WHERE jd.insert_time IS NOT NULL
      AND jd.insert_time >= '2015-12-01'
      AND jd.insert_time <= '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY
      CASE
            WHEN ema.asc_code IN ('DOA', 'DSRO', 'TRC') THEN ema.asc_code
            ELSE 'Other'
      END
ORDER BY
      Xaxis ASC
```